# how safe is the 256 bit encryption used in bank transactions

Tags: ssl

Most of the banks use a 128 bit or 256 bit encryption. What does this mean? Does it mean that the keys used in ssl are 128 bit long or what?

Comment: This might be a better fit for the [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 128 bits and 256 bits are the size of the encryption keys.

Note that this does not really say anything about how secure the underlying encryption algorithm is, since some algorithms (such as MD5) have vulnerabilities which make them easier to decrypt than what the number of bits would indicate (see http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/rogue-ca/).

Comment: 128 bit keys are easy to break. The inventors of rsa recommend use of minimum 1024 bit keys. then why do banks still use 128 bit keys

Comment: Different algorithms using the same key size will provide different level of security, the number of bits is only useful when comparing the same algorithm. For instance, 1024-bits RSA keys are considered unsafe while 128-bits AES keys are considered safe enough for the "foreseeable future" (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_size#Symmetric_algorithm_key_lengths)

Comment: in ssl you exchange keys using rsa right? Now if the keys exchanged have been encrypted with 128 bit rsa key(which is easy to break which you yourself have stated), then the attaked will have the keys.

Comment: SSL and [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) are transport layers, and therefor support a number of encryption algorithm. Check the [secure Google website](https://www.google.com/) for instance, they are using TLS with SHA-1 encryption, which is an algorithm that has never been broken so far. Interestingly, my bank only seems to use 128-bit RSA keys. It could be because of some regulations, as in some countries you are not allowed to use encryption keys larger than a specific size.

Comment: @LamTranDuy: can't downvote comments, but that's certainly wrong: 128 bits isn't the length of the RSA key, but of the negotiated symmetric key.

Comment: @Bruno: I stand corrected. I meant to write MD5, not RSA; Though that'd still be wrong since SHA-1 and MD5 are only used for message authentication (since they're hashing algorithm), and both websites actually rely on 128-bit RC4 keys for symmetric encryption.